# GLUT does not get time with millis accuracy

Tags: c++, opengl, timer, glut

I've got timer issue in GLUT.

`glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME)` only get time with sec accuracy (1000, 2000, 3000...)
and
`glutTimerFunc(...)` works only  when millis parameter is set greater than 1000.

I don't know exactly how GLUT measure time
but I think there's something wrong with my system time setting.

How can I get time with millis accuracy in OpenGL?

Comment: GPU:  http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/opengl-timer-query/    CPU: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

Comment: [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now)?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments above, you could use more reliable C++ date and time utilities like the [std::chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) library. Here is a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    const auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // do something...

    const auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Took " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() << " ms\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for thr answer. Actually, I avoided this problem by using clock() in ctime instead of glutGet, but when Im trying to use glutTimerFunc, I have to rely on glut's time.